# при вводе токена в исмнии нужно что бы выводился один пользователь с таким токеном express.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

при регистрации присваиваеься токен, после если смотреть информацию о пользователе по токену должн высвечиваться один пользователь, но у меня высвечиваються все пользователи
помогите решить эту проблему
index.js

```
app.get('/auth/me', CheckAuth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const user = await getUsers(req.userId);
  
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          message: 'Пользователь не найден'
        });
      }
      
      // Убираем поле passwordHash
      const { passwordHash, ...userData } = user;
  
      res.json(userData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Нет доступа',
      });
    }
  });
```

user.js

```
async function getUsers() {
  const connection = await createConnection();

  try {
    const query = "SELECT id, fullName, email, avatarUrl FROM user";
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(query);
    return rows;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Ошибка при выполнении запроса к базе данных:", error);
    throw error;
  } finally {
    connection.end();
  }
}
```

checkauth.js

```
export default (req, res, next) => {
  const token = (req.headers.authorization || "").replace(/Bearer\s?/, "");

  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "secret123");
      req.userId = decoded.id;
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: "Невалидный токен",
      });
    }
  } else {
    return res.status(403).json({
      message: "Отсутствует токен доступа",
    });
  }
};
```

регистрация

```
{
    "email": "sevka13@gmail.ru",
    "fullName": "Стас",
    "avatarUrl": "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/9K8pKqHnNx5tIzq8T4XCncUvhg5lcmPT8-ISvL99nOh7kCalkVFsAtil5l11HFK1e_O3L5y6ePI=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE3MDE2ODUxOTQsImV4cCI6MTcwNDI3NzE5NH0.G7gOEsj7qEEJmSLar7Ax9NEHHITN9miIcHKGmPEvGys"
}
```

информация которая выводиться

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "Темофей",
        "email": "temoha12@gmail.ru",
        "avatarUrl": "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/9K8pKqHnNx5tIzq8T4XCncUvhg5lcmPT8-ISvL99nOh7kCalkVFsAtil5l11HFK1e_O3L5y6ePI=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
    },
    "1": {
        "id": 33,
        "fullName": "Стас",
        "email": "sevka13@gmail.ru",
        "avatarUrl": "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/9K8pKqHnNx5tIzq8T4XCncUvhg5lcmPT8-ISvL99nOh7kCalkVFsAtil5l11HFK1e_O3L5y6ePI=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj"
    }
}
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: скриншоты сдесь показы для примера, что в иссомнии выходит вот такая информация, не думаю что этот код нужен для скопирования

Comment: Советую перейти по ссылке и почитать все-таки, почему скриншоты в вопросе — плохая идея. Дело не только в копировании.

Comment: так что помогите пж

Comment: `SELECT id, fullName, email, avatarUrl FROM user` **WHERE userID = ??** - Вы пропустили условие в выборке данных

Comment: code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sql: 'SELECT id, fullName, email, avatarUrl FROM user WHERE userID = ??',
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"
}
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1. ошибка.  в исомнии выводиться нет доступа

Comment: Да понятно, что при таком запросе будет ошибка. Вам надо передать параметр при запросе. + ваша функция `getUsers()` не принимает никакие аргументы. Вы не указали, какой библиотекой пользуетесь для доступа к БД, но думаю в документации можно найти, как передать параметр в конструкцию select

Comment: все понятно, я лохушка, исползую mysql workbench (mysql2) и моя голова уже не варит что куда писать, не могли бы вы пожалуйста написать код(((((

Comment: Интересует библиотека nodejs для доступа к БД. А если голова не варит уже, то надо отложить код, отдохнуть, погулять, фильм посмотреть и затем заново взглянуть на код. Если вы ваш код пишите "не думая" и не понимая, что он делает и как, то далеко вы не уплывете... И обзаведитесь хорошей IDE, которая вам будет подсвечивать косяки в коде. Такие как отсутсвие аргументов у функции, неиспользуемые переменные(в той же getUsers у вас переменная fields объявлена, но не используется)

Answer (score 0):

**user.js**

```
async function getUsers(userId) {
    const connection = await createConnection();

    try {
        const query = "SELECT id, fullName, email, avatarUrl FROM user where id = " + userId;
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(query);
        return rows;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Ошибка при выполнении запроса к базе данных:", error);
        throw error;
    } finally {
        connection.end();
    }
}
```